# Condition check in if statment

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

Here is my bash script

```
while ./clipnotify;
do
  SelectedText="$(xsel)"
  CopiedText="$(xsel -b)"
  Check="$(xclip -selection clip -t TARGETS -o)"
  if ["$Check" != *"image"*]; then
    if [[ $SelectedText != *"file:///"* ]]; then
      ModifiedTextPrimary="$(echo "$SelectedText" | tr -s '\n' ' ')"
      echo -n "$ModifiedTextPrimary" | xsel -i
    fi
    if [[ $CopiedText != *"file:///"* ]]; then
      ModifiedTextClipboard="$(echo "$CopiedText" | tr -s '\n' ' '  )"
      echo -n "$ModifiedTextClipboard" | xsel -bi
    fi
  fi
done
```

Output of `xclip -selection clip -t TARGETS -o` when text copied to clipboard :

```
TIMESTAMP
TARGETS
MULTIPLE
SAVE_TARGETS
UTF8_STRING
COMPOUND_TEXT
TEXT
STRING
text/plain;charset=utf-8
text/plain;charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
text/plain
```

Output of `xclip -selection clip -t TARGETS -o` when image copied to clipboard :

```
application/x-qt-image
image/png
image/bmp
image/bw
image/cur
image/eps
image/epsf
image/epsi
image/icns
image/ico
image/jp2
image/jpeg
image/jpg
image/pbm
BITMAP
image/pcx
image/pgm
image/pic
image/ppm
PIXMAP
image/rgb
image/rgba
image/sgi
image/tga
image/tif
image/tiff
image/wbmp
image/webp
image/xbm
image/xpm
TARGETS
MULTIPLE
TIMESTAMP
SAVE_TARGETS
```

What I am trying to do is save output of `xclip -selection clip -t TARGETS -o` to variable `Check` and use `if` statment to check if the variable contains the word "image" so I can detect that clipboard contains an image and disable further execution.

When running the script I get error

```
/home/user/Applications/Scripts/CopyWithoutLinebreaks/debug.sh: line 16: [application/x-qt-image
image/png
image/bmp
image/bw
image/cur
image/eps
image/epsf
image/epsi
image/icns
image/ico
image/jp2
image/jpeg
image/jpg
image/pbm
BITMAP
image/pcx
image/pgm
image/pic
image/ppm
PIXMAP
image/rgb
image/rgba
image/sgi
image/tga
image/tif
image/tiff
image/wbmp
image/webp
image/xbm
image/xpm
TARGETS
MULTIPLE
TIMESTAMP
SAVE_TARGETS: No such file or directory
```

The script works when the check for image condition is removed.

Any way resolve the error ?

Answer (score 3):

Shell scripts are extremely sensitive to lack of white-spaces when using the built-ins for comparison operations

```
if ["$Check" != *"image"*]; then
#  ^^                    ^^       lack of spaces

if [ "$Check" != *"image"* ]; then
#                                 right syntax
```

There should have been a space after the `[` and the start of the next character and similarly before `]` without which the syntax evaluation for the `[..]` fails, producing the error message.